# getting data from Mysql into Spinner by using Php webservice returning json

Tags: android, json

I want a basic example of getting data from Mysql into Spinner by using Php webservice returning json

Comment: i am new to android.i created the webservice in php and made it connection in android.but i dont know how add values which are returned in JSON format into Spinner.

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: i have mentioned what i tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make request and get responce from server as you said it is in json. First parse all fields and store it to the table of sqlite database. Using that filled content you can fill spinner as well.
Here is the link for Filling spinner from database
[link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/06/android-populating-spinner-data-from-sqlite-database/)

Comment: i dont want to use sqllite database.just want to show data in android not store it on user side.

Comment: You can parse data from json and make an Model class which has getter,setters. and fill List<Your model class>, put that List to the the adapter of spinner                                  TempAdapter = new TempAdapter (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myList);                               mySpinner.setAdapter(TempAdapter );

Comment: could u please provide a link which could give some more information regarding this??if possible.